# Run Meta Http line contionally in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and wondering if can only ruth html meta line conditionally.  I basically want to navigate to Mypage only when the if statment is true.

```
<SCRIPT type='"text/javascript"'>
if(true)
Execute the below meta http (Navigate to Mypage.aspx)
else
stay here
</SCRIPT>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://MyPage.aspx">
```

Thanks.

Comment: What condition are you planning to check in your `if` statement? In other words, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: In the if statment, i will check navigator.userAgent to check if user is coming from mobile browser and if that is true, i will redirect him/her to Mypage.aspx other wise I dont do anything (Stay in the same page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you need directly in Javascript using

```
if (your_condition) 
  { window.location.href="newpage.htm"  }
```

if you want to keep the 10 second wait, use

```
if (your_condition) 
  { setTimeout(function() { window.location.href="newpage.htm" }, 10000); }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript allows one to write HTML to the document while it is being loaded using `document.write("string here")`. However, it is much better to use the `window.location` object, which contains the various parts of the URL. In your case, you want to set `window.location.href` (the entire URL) to the redirect destination. You can attempt to check for a mobile browser using a regular expression, also known as a regexp.

Without the ten second delay: (The regexp is the one Wikipedia uses for the redirect to its mobile site.)

```
if(/(Android|iPhone|iPod|webOS|NetFront|Opera Mini|SEMC-Browser|PlayStation Portable|Nintendo Wii|BlackBerry)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location.href = "page_you_want_to_redirect_to";
}
```

*In JavaScript, a regexp is an object. Its `.test` method returns a Boolean value (true/false) indicating whether the regexp matches the string argument.*

With the ten second delay:

```
if(/(Android|iPhone|iPod|webOS|NetFront|Opera Mini|SEMC-Browser|PlayStation Portable|Nintendo Wii|BlackBerry)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "page_you_want_to_redirect_to";
    }, 10000);
}
```

*What is setTimeout? setTimeout is the JavaScript function to run code after a time delay in milliseconds [10000 ms = 10 s]. The code to be run is contained within `function() { ... }`, which creates a closure (an essential feature of JavaScript).*